# Custom LinearLayout with inflate xml and child node

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom navigation class where there are common views therefore i was thinking to put them into one layout which is to be inflated by the custom class and on the main layout ill put some navigation item on it.

Currently when i extends linearlayout, the views in the xml replaces all the views in the inflated view (i put this code on constructor)

```
((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigation_group, this ,true);
```

Is there a way where i could inflate a layout and get the child of the xml implementation and put it on one view? like

layout to be inflated

```
<com.mycompany.NavigationGroup>
   <Text android:text="title" ... />
   <Button android:text="collapse" ... />
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/navigationItemHolder ... />
   <Text android:text="descriptions" ... />
</com.mycompany.NavigationGroup>
```

used in main layout

```
<com.mycompany.NavigationGroup>
   <Button android:text="menu 1" />
   <Button android:text="menu 2" />
</com.mycompany.NavigationGroup>
```

My question is how could i put menu 1 & menu 2 inside navigationItemHolder? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do what you are asking.  I would rephrase your question to discuss what type of layout you want to achieve and someone can help you determine how to do that.

Comment: nice question, but it could have been better phrased.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this programmatically after you inflate your layout. I believe you can do something like this:

```
YourLayout layout = (YourLayout)((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigation_group, this ,true);
layout.((LinearLayout)getChildAt (3)).addView (yourNavigationGroup);
```